# Download SharePoint List Attachment with REST API

Tags: api, sharepoint, sharepoint-list

Using the SharePoint REST API, I can download a file from a Document Library no issue.  But now I want to download an Attachment from a List.

I can find my list, and I can list my Attachments with the SP or Graph API no issue. example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http  or a /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items(1)/AttachmentFiles give me a nice list of my Attachment URLs, but not the file itself.

If I try a GET with Authorization on the URL I get a 401.  But If I just paste the URL in a browser it downloads.

I have seen its possible with SP Powershell, but I am not able to use that in this solution.

I am not able to find a API to download it.  Is this possible?

Bonus points if I can just get it as a Base64 string.

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop on the attachments and append `/$value` to retrieve the data.
You can find more details in Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-attached-to-list-items-by-using-rest

```
GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{list_title}')/items({item_id})/AttachmentFiles('{file_name}')/$value
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```